# longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length using MAP2 function

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, ggplot2

I am trying to generate plots per subject and lbtestcd using the following code.
Basically I am trying to iterate over two lists from a data frame using `map2` function and my anonymous function is `ggplot` to generate the plots. I get the following warning messages when run my code. can some help me please?

> Warning messages:
> 1: In USUBJID == .x :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> 2: In LBTESTCD == .y :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sqldf)

# Get List of subjects and testcds and convert to dataframe 

sub_list  <- data.frame(subs = unique(adhoc_lb$USUBJID))
test_list <- data.frame(testcd = unique(adhoc_lb$LBTESTCD))


# create a data frame with subjects and testcds
mer <- sqldf("select a.*,b.*
              from sub_list as a , test_list as b")

# Each Graph in a separate page
allplots <- map2(.x=mer[1], .y=mer[2] ,.f= ~ (adhoc_lb %>% 
            filter(USUBJID == .x | LBTESTCD == .y) %>%     
            ggplot(aes(x = VISITNUM, y = AVAL)) +
            geom_point()))
```

Comment: The warning message is pretty explicit.  `mer[1]` and `mer[2]` are not the same length or integer multiples of each others length.  Have you checked the length of each?

Comment: This is how i am checking the length and both of them are of same length   > length(mer[1])
[1] 1
> length(mer[2])
[1] 1

Comment: Hmmm...  Did you visually inspect `mer[1]` and `mer[2]` to see what they look like?

Comment: allplots <- map2(.x=mer$subs, .y=mer$testcd ,.f= ~ (adhoc_lb %>% 
            filter(USUBJID == .x | LBTESTCD == .y) %>%     
            ggplot(aes(x = VISITNUM, y = AVAL)) +
            geom_point()))      changing mer[1] ,mer[2] to mer$subs and mer$testcd seems to work, but again nor sure why the previous dint work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mer[1]` would return a dataframe back. Use `mer[[1]]` or `mer[, 1]` which would give you back a vector similar to when you use `$` to access dataframe column value.

```
library(tidyverse)

allplots <- map2(.x=mer[[1]], .y=mer[[2]] ,
                 .f= ~ adhoc_lb %>% 
                        filter(USUBJID == .x | LBTESTCD == .y) %>%     
                        ggplot(aes(x = VISITNUM, y = AVAL)) + geom_point())
```

Comment: mer[[1]] or mer$subs both work. Thank you